# Laravel 4 Query Builder SQL Statement

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4

Good day, I have this SQL statement and I'm having a difficulty on how to convert this in Laravel Query.

I read the docs in http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queries and I'm confused. Any help would do.

```
SELECT count(*) FROM `transactions` WHERE `borrower_id` = 2 
            AND `book_id` = 2 AND (
                (
                    `reservedDate` IS NOT NULL 
                    and `borrowedDate` IS NULL
                ) 
                OR (
                    `borrowedDate` IS NOT NULL 
                    AND `returnedDate` IS NULL
                )
            )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I try to build this query by reading the documentations from Laravel. Still haven't tested it yet but hope it could give you the right direction.

Maybe next time, you should show your own query (it's ok if it's not correct). It's easier to get start from there.

```
$super_query = DB::table('transactions')->where('borrower_id' , '=' , 2)->where('book_id', '=' , 2)->where( function ( $query ) {
$query->where(function ($query1) {
    $query1->whereNotNull('reservedDate')->whereNull('borrowedDate')
)->orWhere(function ($query2) {
    $query2->whereNotNUll('borrowedDate')->whereNull('returnedDate')
})  
})->count();
```

Comment: Thank you! I'll show next my query, next time...I freaked out.

Comment: Why downvote? Any idea to improve this answer? Thanks

Comment: @yowza if you ok with the anser just mark it as correct answer. Thanks

Comment: @yowza, my answer is the earliest one, and the one that you marked as correct looks exactly the same :)

Comment: oh, I'm sorry about that mate...I change the mark now (:, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
    DB::table('transactions')
  ->Where('borrower_id', '=', 2)
  ->Where('book_id', '=', 2)
  ->where(function($query)
  {
    $query->where(function($query1) {
      $query1->whereNotNull('reservedDate')
             ->whereNull('borrowedDate');

    })
    ->orWhere(function($query2) {
      $query2->whereNotNull('borrowedDate')
             ->whereNull('returnedDate');
  });
})->count();
```

try this.. this will result into

```
select count(*) from `transactions` where `borrower_id` = 2 and `book_id` = 2 and ((`reservedDate` is not null and `borrowedDate` is null) or (`borrowedDate` is not null and `returnedDate` is null))
```

Comment: Man, you beat me by 30 seconds!

Comment: @JaredEitnier I'm still new here... just signing up to help... i don't know this is a contest

Comment: Oh no, it's not a _contest_ per-se, just a friendly game of who can get the checkmark first :) Welcome.

Comment: @JaredEitnier Good game, well played... hahah

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

**Eloquent**

```
Transactions::where('borrower_id', '=', 2)
    ->where('book_id', '=', 2)
    ->where(function($query)
    {
        $query->whereNotNull('reservedDate')
                ->whereNull('borrowedDate');
    })
    ->orWhere(function($query)
    {
        $query->whereNotNull('borrowedDate')
                ->whereNull('returnedDate');
    })
    ->count();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
book::count()->where('borrower_id','=','2','book_id','=',2)
```